# Not able to create a docker container using ansible

Tags: python, docker, ansible

#### Issue -1

I installed docker docker-py, pip, python set-up tools,docker-io via ansible.

I tried to install container inside the docker using "ansible-container init", ansible-container build" but i get a syntax error,

```
***Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible-container", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ansible-container==0.3.0', 'console_scripts', 'ansible-container')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 560, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2648, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2302, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2308, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/container/cli.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import engine
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/container/engine.py", line 554
    special_set = {'.', ':'}
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax***
```

#### Issue 2

I even tried build and running using docker-images and docker-container in the yaml file.

I get some-otherlike below.

```
***TASK [Build Docker image from Dockerfiles.] ************************************
ok: [192.168.56.104]
TASK [Run the test container.] *************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
fatal: [192.168.56.104]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UTbJkn/ansible_module_docker_container.py\", line 2007, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UTbJkn/ansible_module_docker_container.py\", line 2000, in main\n    cm = ContainerManager(client)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UTbJkn/ansible_module_docker_container.py\", line 1652, in __init__\n    self.present(state)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UTbJkn/ansible_module_docker_container.py\", line 1677, in present\n    different, differences = container.has_different_configuration(image)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UTbJkn/ansible_module_docker_container.py\", line 1220, in has_different_configuration\n    expected_exposed=[re.sub(r'/.+$', '', p) for p in config.get('ExposedPorts', dict()).keys()],\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/vagrant/playbook/dockerinstall.retry***
```

My code in yaml was like this,

```
   - name: Build Docker image from Dockerfiles.
     docker_image:
        name: test
        path: test
        state: build
   - name: Run the test container.
     docker_container:
        image: test:latest
        name: test
        state: present
```

Answer (score 0):

Sriram, thank-you for your interest in Ansible Container, and for taking the time to post a question.

It looks like the error in **Issue-1** is related to the version of Python. I see it's referencing `/usr/lib/python2.6`. Switch to 2.7+, and that should go away.

In **Issue-2** it looks like you posted a copy of your `main.yml`. You shouldn't be using `docker_image` or `docker_container` modules. I'll attempt to explain, but you may find it helpful to review our [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/getting_started.html)

The idea is to use Ansible Container to first `build` an image. For example, suppose you want to run an Nginx web server. You would start by building an image capable of running the server, and so your `main.yml` would then look something like the following:

```
- name: Install nginx
  hosts: web
  roles:
  - j00bar.nginx-container
```

And your `container.yml` might look like the following:

```
Version: 2
services:
  nginx:
    image: centos:7
    ports:
    - "8000:80"
    user: 'nginx'
    command: ['/usr/bin/dumb-init', 'nginx', '-c', '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf']
```

And, of course, you would need to add the role to `requirements.yml`, which will look like this:

```
- role: j00bar.nginx-container
```

To build the image, execute `ansible-container build`. This will start a new container called `web` based on the `centos:7` image, and the `build` container.

The `build` container will download the role, and execute the `main.yml` playbook against the `web` container. When it's finished it will commit a copy of the `web` container, creating a new image.

Now you're ready to run an Nginx server by executing `ansible-container run`. This time it will start a `web` container using the new image.

Hopefully that makes sense. But, again, please take a look at the [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/getting_started.html).

Comment: Quick comment. No where in the getting started guide does it reference a main.yml. It isn't obvious from those docs what the purpose of main.yaml is. What do I put in my main.yml vs container.yml.  Why is not created by ansible-container init? What is the relation between the two?  How does the services.nginx hook to hosts:web? Why do the docs show roles appearing in the container.yml?